# How is Goku able to survive in Space?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super episode 13 after losing the Super Saiyan God power, how is Goku able to breathe and survive in space.

As we all know that Saiyans can't breathe in Space then how is he able to continue fighting with Beerus in Space in SSJ2 form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just speculation but I believe Saiyans are capable of breathing in space for short periods of time unlike Freeza who can live without oxygen indefinitely.

Also assuming Super follows The battle of gods movie, Goku could still be within/close to the earth's atmosphere.

Bardock has also been seen flying through space in his special although that was technically filler.

The most likely answer is that it is simply a retcon, Akira Toriyama is known to have a bad memory when it comes to the Dragon Ball universe and so it is likely that he just simply forgot that Saiyans were incapable of doing so.

Comment: Goku is indeed still in the stratosphere according to the Dragon Ball Super comics, but a person shouldn't be able to be there for a long period of time though.

Comment: [Here](http://mangafox.me/manga/dragon_ball/v26/c115/9.html) it is shown that Goku is able to hold his breath for a very long time.

Comment: There is also a scene where Vegeta destroys planet Arlia. Vegeta and Nappa are standing in their space pods with the hatch open as Vegeta fires a beam at the planet. They proceed to laugh as the planet explodes.

Answer (score 3):

Goku has been able to survive in space since OG Dragon Ball. He went to the moon using his power poll and had no problem being in a vacuum.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Vegeta and Nappa also share a scene where they are seemingly in space, yet right next to a planet. They are both standing outside their pods, then obliterate the planet and leave. Similar events occur with Bardock attacking Frieza near planet Vegeta and Goku fighting Beerus near Earth.

While I am not 100% sure if the creators meant to do this (having the above mentioned characters near the planets) they actually make it scientifically accurate. The same can even be said when Pan is flying in "space" with Hercule and co. during a Dragon Ball Super episode.

They are always in the upper atmosphere of the planet that they are near. While the air is much colder, and thinner then ground level conditions, it would still be breathable. For sayians since they are a hell of a lot more durable then the average human, they can easily survive in the upper atmosphere.

Comment: Beerus is a deity and he can't breathe in space. He needs his attendant to create a barrier around him. So, this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Goku became a god with his godly form, he also absorbed the godly ki so Goku is technically a god now so he should be able to survive space, plus the Null Realm is basically space so yeah, Goku would be fine in space.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Comment: The null realm, the void outside the multiverse where the tournament of power happened.

Comment: Well, not really. It is clearly mentioned in Dragon Ball Super Ch 49 by Vegeta that saiyans can not survive in space.